# Access parent property name from child class

Tags: c#, oop, reflection

I have a classes like:

```
class A {
    public B prop1 {get; set;}
    public B prop2 {get; set;}
}

class B {
    public B {
        // which name of my parent property - prop1 or prop2?
    }
}
```

How can I find out from the constructor of class B: the value of which of the properties of the parent class (prop1 or prop2) this instance of class B is?

Comment: Store that value when you create an instance of B.

Comment: In the constructor the instance of B will not be associated with A at all. The assignment to prop1 or prop2 can only happen after the constructor completes.

Comment: @rene, It's simple, but not an elegant solution. I want an elegant, with reflection etc

Comment: @Titian, ok, how to access this after constructor completes?

Comment: Reflection is not elegant.

Comment: Maybe not reflection, I don't know. But more elegant than simply pass a conctructor parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor the instance if class B be will not be associated with A at all. The assignment to prop1 or prop2 can only happen after the constructor completes.

Without a direct reference in B to A there is no way for B to know what property it is related to. If B has a reference to A, it could check each property of A and see which is equal to it, but this is not a particularly pretty solution.

Another strategy you could use is to do some work in the property of A to mark the instance of B as belonging to A through prop1 or prop2. In the implementation below I use `CallerMemberName` so as not to pass the name as a string, the compiler will pass it to us when the method is invoked

```
class A
{
    private B _prop1;
    public B prop1
    {
        get => _prop1;
        set => SetProp(value, ref _prop1);
    }

    private B _prop2;
    public B prop2
    {
        get => _prop2;
        set => SetProp(value, ref _prop2);
    }

    private void SetProp(B value, ref B field, [CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        if(field != null) field.Association = null;
        field = value;
        if (field != null) field.Association = propName;
    }

}

class B
{
    public string Association { get; set; }
}
```